# What is the best way to have kwh/year in a variable

Tags: java

I wanted to know something like if i have a variable like 200kwh/year ..whats the best way to put into a variable.?

Comment: why `int` or `double` type are unappropriate?

Comment: Could you please explain why would `int` or `double` not work? You can store the value, and the units (i.e. `kwh/year`) would be implied.

Comment: Are you asking what the best data-type is?

Comment: @oli .if i want to store 22cent/kwh...would it be good to store in double or float like double i = .22 or float i=.22

Comment: @SaurabhKumar does that mean you need to store units to do calculations, where the output unit is calculated also? I.e. 200kwh/year*22cent/kwh=4400cent/year with the unit cent/year calulcated instead of hardcoded/implied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways that you could store it; the simplest being using an `int`, `float`, `double`, or if you are feeling extra precise, `BigDecimal`.

Remember to use the variable name to keep it meaningful and easy to understand:

**Example:**

```
double kilowattsPerYear = 200.00d;
int kilowattsPerYear = 200;
float kilowattsPerYear = 200.00f;
BigDecimal kilowattsPeryear = new BigDecimal("200.00"); //Accepts Several Types
```

Comment: +1 also consider using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if exact precision is necessary or very large (or small) numbers are needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on the application.**

The simple answer, like if this is for homework, is just use a `float` or a `double`.  A `float` will give you plenty of resolution for homework and will take the smallest amount of memory.  If you need a very very specific number, say for scientific application, you may want to use a `double`.  The size of the variable probably makes no difference unless you're going to have millions of data points, need to save memory, and don't need the extra resolution.

If you use an `int`, you will restrict yourself to only whole number data.  However, if this is a billing application, the company may bill, for example, in increments of `0.001` kwh.  If this is the case, storing it as an `int` value number of `0.001` kwh will eliminate the rounding errors that may occur during floating point operations.  This approach is commonly used when dealing with money.

Answer (score 1):

Create a customise data type something like

```
public class CustUnit{

private BigDecimal value;
private String unit;

         public CustUnit(String/double/int/long value,String unit){
          this.value = new BigDecimal(value);
          this.unit = unit;
}

public String getValue(){
 return this.value.toString + this.unit;;
}

}
```

I think this will more flexible. you can use it for different type of unit and value.

Comment: +1 It will also allow you to do calculations with units and have a way to verify you are using the right variables/operations in calculations(like 10kWh/year + 22cent/kWh instead of *).

Answer (score -2):

Isn't Kwh = kilo watts hour. Using SI Kwh per year is kilo watts?

Therefore an integer may suffice.

Comment: What does cancelling the units have to do with it being an integer value?

Comment: I said it may suffice - if you are talking about the number of killo watts a household uses in a year. As to the data type - that depends on what are you going to be doing with the number.